# I'm in need of help for a prime counting program with no error, howerver still crashing (C#)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pi_szamlalo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int limit = 100;
            List<int> prime = new List<int>();
            prime.Add(2);
            for (int number = 3; number <= limit; number = number + 1)
            {
                foreach(int prime2 in prime) //here is the error at "in"
                {
                    if (number % prime2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(number + " is not a prime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(number + " is a prime");
                        prime.Add(number);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea would be that the program tries to divide all the whole numbers to the limit with the already known primes. If the remainder is zero in one of the cases, the program will move on to the next.

However, if the program could not find a prime number in the list of primes, it will add it to the list, and say it's a prime.

So, in Visual Studio 2013, there are no sign of errors, except the crash.
Here is the error message  [The Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccSEt.png)

It is in hungarian, it says something like this:
The list has been modified, it may be that the operation cannot be runned.

Comment: Why do you think “it crash”? Does it show an error message? You need to [tell us the message](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Also you need to [learn how to use a debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: In VS, press Ctrl + Alt + E, check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", run your program again. You should see more exceptions thrown that previous runs.

Comment: You're using a `foreach` statement on a collection that you then add a value to. This isn't allowed. You can get round this by using `foreach (int prime2 in prime.ToList())` as that creates a copy of the list which isn't modified.

Comment: You also need to run through the whole list of primes before deciding if a number is prime - currently you're writing whether it is or isn't a prime each time you test it: you can only determine that when you've _finished_ testing, which is after the `foreach` loop finishes, at which point you can add the value to the list without an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example taking into account my comment above: you need to run through the whole list of primes before deciding if a number is prime - currently you're writing whether it is or isn't a prime each time you test it: you can only determine that when you've finished testing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int limit = 100;
        List<int> prime = new List<int>();
        prime.Add(2);
        for (int number = 3; number <= limit; number = number + 1)
        {
            bool isPrime = true;

            foreach (int prime2 in prime)
            {
                if (number % prime2 == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number + " is a prime");
                prime.Add(number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number + " is not a prime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I mean, it was just 15 minutes, and it was solved! :D So thanks for the replies, I will chek it out :)